# Shorten code in search function of an inventory app

Tags: c#, search

**Introduction**

I want to create an Inventory App in C#. I was thinking of someone who sells a few products and only needs to have a few product properties in the program to search or sort by, and then click on ‘sold’ or click on ‘order’. An Excel export is also to be realised.

Today, I wrote my search function. The search term is entered in a text box. One can enclose the search term in inverted commas "to find exactly this whole sentence"; one can also write `A Or B` to find both products; one can also write `A -B` to find A, but not B. So with the latter example, you can exclude certain words.

There is a list of entries in my programme. It contains instances of the class `Entry`. The class `Entry` also includes an instance of the class `Product`.

At the end of the search function, however, another list – `search_results` – is filled. This is sorted.

**My question**

I would like to know if there is anything I can do to improve this. It seems like a lot of lines of code to me...

**Edit:** This is a *Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)* with .Net Framework 4.8

[image]

**FormMain.cs**

```
/// <summary>
        /// all Data
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly List<Entry> AllEntries = new List<Entry>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Suchergebnisse
        /// </summary>
        private List<Entry> search_results = null;

private enum Esort_criterion
        {
            alphabetical,
            by_Creation_Time
        }
        private Esort_criterion Sort_Criterion;
```

```
private void TextBox_seek_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && !System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_seek.Text))
            {
                seek(TextBox_seek.Text);
            }
        }
```

```
private async void seek(string SearchTerm)
        {

            // Remove entries from the previous search (if there are any).
            if (search_results != null && search_results.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Entry E in search_results)
                {
                    foreach (Bitmap Image in E.TheProduct.ListOfPhotos)
                    {
                        if (Image != null)
                        {
                            Image.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
                search_results.Clear();
            }

            List<Entry> sorted_search_results = await Task.Run(() => seekAsync(SearchTerm));

            if (sorted_search_results == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (sorted_search_results.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no matches found",
                                "Inventory App – Suche",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Information);// Do not write ‘return’
            }

            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(search_results.Select(x => $"{x.TheProduct.BrandName}{"\t"}{x.TheProduct.ModelName}{"\t"}{x.TheProduct.DescriptionOrNotes}{"\t"}{Math.Round(x.TheProduct.SellingPrice, 2)} €").ToArray());
        }

        private List<Entry> seekAsync(string SearchTerm)
        {
            search_results = new List<Entry>();

            char[] CharArray = SearchTerm.ToCharArray();
            string[] StringArray1 = SearchTerm.Split(new[] { " Or ", " or " }, 3, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string[] StringArray2 = SearchTerm.Split(new[] { " -" }, 3, StringSplitOptions.None);

            // "Mehrere Wörter zusammenhängend" (exaktes Ergebnis)
            if (CharArray.First() == '"' && CharArray.Last() == '"')
            {
                foreach (Entry E in AllEntries)
                {
                    if (E.TheProduct.BrandName.Contains(SearchTerm.Split('"')[1]) ||
                        E.TheProduct.ModelName.Contains(SearchTerm.Split('"')[1]))
                    {
                        List<Bitmap> NewBitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();

                        foreach (string FullFileName in E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos)
                        {
                            if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullFileName))
                            {
                                NewBitmaps.Add(new Bitmap(FullFileName));
                            }
                        }
                        // NEUE Instanzen erzeugen, sonst wird auf denselben Speicherbereich gezeigt.
                        // Create NEW instances, otherwise the same memory area is pointed to. 
                        search_results.Add(new Entry(
                                            E.Employee_who_created_Entry,
                                            E.CreationTime,
                                            E.Changed_by_Employee,
                                            E.LastChangeTime,
                                            new Product(
                                                E.TheProduct.BrandName,
                                                E.TheProduct.ModelName,
                                                E.TheProduct.Size,
                                                E.TheProduct.DescriptionOrNotes,
                                                NewBitmaps,
                                                E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos,
                                                E.TheProduct.PurchasePrice,
                                                E.TheProduct.SellingPrice)
                                            )
                            );
                        search_results.Last().TheProduct.are_images_loaded = (new bool[E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos.Count]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if ((SearchTerm.Contains(" Or ") ^ SearchTerm.Contains(" or ")) && StringArray1.Length >= 2)
            {
                foreach (Entry E in AllEntries)
                {
                    foreach (string part in StringArray1)
                    {
                        if (E.TheProduct.BrandName.Contains(part) ||
                            E.TheProduct.ModelName.Contains(part))
                        {
                            List<Bitmap> NewBitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();

                            foreach (string FullFileName in E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos)
                            {
                                if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullFileName))
                                {
                                    NewBitmaps.Add(new Bitmap(FullFileName));
                                }
                            }
                            // NEUE Instanzen erzeugen, sonst wird auf denselben Speicherbereich gezeigt.
                            // Create NEW instances, otherwise the same memory area is pointed to. 
                            search_results.Add(new Entry(
                                               E.Employee_who_created_Entry,
                                               E.CreationTime,
                                               E.Changed_by_Employee,
                                               E.LastChangeTime,
                                               new Product(
                                                        E.TheProduct.BrandName,
                                                        E.TheProduct.ModelName,
                                                        E.TheProduct.Size,
                                                        E.TheProduct.DescriptionOrNotes,
                                                        NewBitmaps,
                                                        E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos,
                                                        E.TheProduct.PurchasePrice,
                                                        E.TheProduct.SellingPrice)
                                                    )
                                    );
                            search_results.Last().TheProduct.are_images_loaded = (new bool[E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos.Count]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (StringArray2.Length >= 2) // A, but NOT B
            {
                foreach (Entry E in AllEntries)
                {

                    if ((E.TheProduct.BrandName.Contains(StringArray2[0]) ||
                         E.TheProduct.ModelName.Contains(StringArray2[0])) &&
                         !E.TheProduct.BrandName.Contains(StringArray2[1]) &&
                         (!E.TheProduct.ModelName.Contains(StringArray2[1])))
                    {
                         List<Bitmap> NewBitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();

                         foreach (string FullFileName in E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos)
                         {
                             if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullFileName))
                             {
                                 NewBitmaps.Add(new Bitmap(FullFileName));
                             }
                         }
                         // NEUE Instanzen erzeugen, sonst wird auf denselben Speicherbereich gezeigt.
                         // Create NEW instances, otherwise the same memory area is pointed to. 
                         search_results.Add(new Entry(
                                            E.Employee_who_created_Entry,
                                            E.CreationTime,
                                            E.Changed_by_Employee,
                                            E.LastChangeTime,
                                            new Product(
                                                        E.TheProduct.BrandName,
                                                        E.TheProduct.ModelName,
                                                        E.TheProduct.Size,
                                                        E.TheProduct.DescriptionOrNotes,
                                                        NewBitmaps,
                                                        E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos,
                                                        E.TheProduct.PurchasePrice,
                                                        E.TheProduct.SellingPrice)
                                                    )
                                    );
                         search_results.Last().TheProduct.are_images_loaded = (new bool[E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos.Count]);
                    }       
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Entry E in AllEntries)
                {
                    if (E.TheProduct.BrandName.Contains(SearchTerm) ||
                        E.TheProduct.ModelName.Contains(SearchTerm))
                    {
                        List<Bitmap> NewBitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();

                        foreach (string FullFileName in E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos)
                        {
                            if (System.IO.File.Exists(FullFileName))
                            {
                                NewBitmaps.Add(new Bitmap(FullFileName));
                            }
                        }
                        // NEUE Instanzen erzeugen, sonst wird auf denselben Speicherbereich gezeigt.
                        // Create NEW instances, otherwise the same memory area is pointed to. 
                        search_results.Add(new Entry(
                                           E.Employee_who_created_Entry,
                                           E.CreationTime,
                                           E.Changed_by_Employee,
                                           E.LastChangeTime,
                                           new Product(
                                                    E.TheProduct.BrandName,
                                                    E.TheProduct.ModelName,
                                                    E.TheProduct.Size,
                                                    E.TheProduct.DescriptionOrNotes,
                                                    NewBitmaps,
                                                    E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos,
                                                    E.TheProduct.PurchasePrice,
                                                    E.TheProduct.SellingPrice)
                                                    )
                                    );
                        search_results.Last().TheProduct.are_images_loaded = (new bool[E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos.Count]);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Einschub: Falls vor dem Bedienen der Suche verworfen wurden, müssen sie nun doch geladen werden. Das ist oben passiert. Hier wird das Boolean-Array befüllt.
            //If images were disposed before operating the search, they must now be loaded after all. This is what happened above. Here, the Boolean array is filled.

            foreach (Entry search_result in search_results)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < search_result.TheProduct.are_images_loaded.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!search_result.TheProduct.are_images_loaded[i])
                    {
                        search_result.TheProduct.are_images_loaded[i] = true;
                    }          
                }
            }

            switch (Sort_Criterion)
            {
                case Esort_criterion.alphabetical:
                    {
                        search_results.Sort((x, y) =>
                        {
                            int r = StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x.TheProduct.BrandName, y.TheProduct.BrandName);
                            return r;
                        });
                        if(CheckBox_reverse.Checked)
                        {
                            search_results.Reverse();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case Esort_criterion.by_Creation_Time:
                    {
                        search_results.Sort((x, y) => x.CreationTime.CompareTo(y.CreationTime));
                        if (CheckBox_reverse.Checked)
                        {
                            search_results.Reverse();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }

            return search_results;
        }
```

#### So that you can reproduce this, I'm giving you the code of the classes here.

**Entries.cs**

```
using System;

namespace IA
{
    public sealed class Entry
    {
        public int Employee_who_created_Entry;
        public DateTime CreationTime;
        /// <summary>
        ///      in years
        ///      </summary>
        public double Age;
        public int Changed_by_Employee;
        public DateTime LastChangeTime;
        public Product TheProduct;

        public Entry(int Employee_who_created_Entry,
                     DateTime CreationTime,
                     int Changed_by_Employee,
                     DateTime LastChangeTime,
                     Product TheProduct)
        {
            this.Employee_who_created_Entry = Employee_who_created_Entry;
            this.CreationTime = CreationTime;
            this.Age = (DateTime.Now - this.CreationTime).TotalDays / 365.0;
            this.Changed_by_Employee = Changed_by_Employee;
            this.LastChangeTime = LastChangeTime;
            this.TheProduct = TheProduct;
        }
    }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace IA
{
    public sealed class Product
    {
        public string BrandName;
        public string ModelName;
        /// <summary>
        /// in millimetres
        /// </summary>
        public struct SSize
        {
            public UInt32 Length;
            public UInt32 Width;
            public UInt32 Height;
        }
        public SSize Size;

        public string DescriptionOrNotes;
        public List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> ListOfPhotos;
        public List<string> ListOfPathsOfThePhotos;
        public bool[] are_images_loaded;
        public decimal PurchasePrice;
        public decimal SellingPrice;

        public Product(string BrandName,
                       string ModelName,
                       SSize Size,
                       string DescriptionOrNotes,
                       List<System.Drawing.Bitmap> ListOfPhotos,
                       List<string> ListOfPathsOfThePhotos,
                       decimal PurchasePrice,
                       decimal SellingPrice)
        {
            this.BrandName = BrandName;
            this.ModelName = ModelName;
            this.Size = Size;
            this.DescriptionOrNotes = DescriptionOrNotes;
            this.ListOfPhotos = ListOfPhotos;
            this.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos = ListOfPathsOfThePhotos;
            this.PurchasePrice = PurchasePrice;
            this.SellingPrice = SellingPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please use `English`

Answer (score 3):

Quick remarks:

- Please [follow the guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). No underscores in names of classes etc., proper casing (pascal/camel),...
- Don't put all your code in a single file. Most of your `seek` method should be in a separate class that returns a result of sort. Separate your UI from your back-end logic.
- You have a `seekAsync` method that isn't `async`, and a `seek` method that is.
- Don't pointlessly abbreviate. `E` is totally unclear.
- Use descriptive name. `StringArray1` and `StringArray2` tell me nothing. `StringArray2[0]` tells me even less.
- `ListOfPathsOfThePhotos` is a bad name in several ways. Why not simply call it `PhotoPaths`? `TheProduct` is also a bad property name: just call it `Product`.
- Your code contains repeated blocks. Each time you call `new Entry(` I see the same parameters. Have a constructor that accepts an `Entry` plus any additional data (e.g. `NewBitmaps`) and do all the necessary actions in that constructor. Same with `foreach (string FullFileName in E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos)`.
- `search_results.Last().TheProduct.are_images_loaded = (new bool[E.TheProduct.ListOfPathsOfThePhotos.Count]);` seems like a hacky solution. Why not return a class with one property that is the list of results, and another that is this Boolean?
- Why don't you use LINQ instead of things like this: `search_results.Sort((x, y) => x.CreationTime.CompareTo(y.CreationTime));`? Arguably, even much of your search logic could be replaced by much simpler and easier to read LINQ commands that filter through `AllEntries`, you can then use the results of those commands to construct the list of `search_results`.
- So much of your code looks "ancient". Did you base this on very old example code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)
I'll take a look and improve it. I wanted to mention one more thing: This is just my source code. The reason I don't use LINQ is that I'm actually programming in VB.NET and am now gradually trying my hand at C#. I've already seen Visual Studio make suggestions with LINQ code. This is still too "confusing" for me.

Comment: What else would you call "StringArray1"? `Strings separated by the word or`?

Comment: I agree with you that the method is now so big that it should be in a separte class. 